# The dynamic of a stack

Tags: c++, c, stack

I need a bit of help with understanding the dymanic of a stack in data structures.

I have this postfixed notation:

```
a b c d * + 3 * + 5 6 2 c * + * +
```

The evaluation will be:

```
a + 3b + 3cd + 30 + 10c
```

But what is the algorithm to find out the dynamic of this stack?

LE: thank you mates for helping me to understand it.

```
-> a, b, c, d 
-> a, b c * d 
-> a, b + c * d, 3 
-> 3 * (b + c * d), a 
-> 2 * c, 6, 5, a + (b + c * d) + 3
-> 5 * (6 + 2 * c), a + (b + c * d) + 3
-> a + (b + c * d) + 3 + 5 * (6 + 2 * c)
```

I see that below are a few more correct explications too. I did it here as detailed as I could to be easier to understand if someone else will need it.

Comment: u mean dynamic algorithm for postfix?

Comment: `((c*d)+b)*3 + a + ((2*c)+6)*5` Thats about it. Don't think I missed anything.

Comment: Make a pile of cards each having a variable, number or operator and simulate manually

Comment: tip: try to write a function and use it with the C/C++ calling convention, everything done in assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every element in the sequence:

- If the element is an operand, push it to the stack. (The stack grows by one.)
- If the element is an operator, pop two elements from the stack, apply the operator, push the result back to the stack. (The stack shrinks by one.)

Comment: @user2485710 So you think the OP was talking about the execution stack? Well, there's no one answer to that, if that's what's being asked.

Comment: usually it's the "stack" that people refer to .

Answer (score 2):

There are two main rules:

- If the element is an operand, push it on the stack
- If it is an operator, do the operation by popping two elements out and then push the result on the stack again

### Example:

1) stack is filled with abcd

```
a b c d
```

2) * is encountered, c and d are popped, c*d is performed and the result is pushed on the stack

```
a b cd
```

3) + is encountered, b+cd is computed

```
a b+cd
```

3) 3 is pushed on the stack

```
a b+cd 3
```

4) * is encountered and (b+cd) * 3 = 3b + 3cd is computed

```
a 3(b+cd)
```

5) + is encountered and a + 3(b+cd) is computed

```
a+3(b+cd) (one element on the stack)
```

6) 5, 6, 2, c are pushed

```
a+3(b+cd) 5 6 2 c
```

7) * is encountered

```
a+3(b+cd) 5 6 2*c
```

8) + is encountered

```
a+3(b+cd) 5 6+2*c
```

9) * is encountered

```
a+3(b+cd) 5*(6+2*c)
```

10) + is encountered

```
a+3(b+cd)+5*(6+2*c)
```

Grand-total is

```
a + 3b + 3cd + 30 + 10c
```

as expected

---

References: [Postfix evaluation with a stack](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/postfix-evaluation/)

Answer (score 1):

**The stack progression is:**

```
a b c d f g 3 h i 5 6 2 c j k m n
  a b c b a g a   i 5 6 2 6 5 i
    a b a   a       i 5 6 5 i
      a               i 5 i
                        i
```

**Where:**

```
f = d*c
g = d*c+b
h = 3*(d*c+b)
i = 3*(d*c+b)+a
j = c*2
k = c*2+6
m = (c*2+6)*5
n = (c*2+6)*5+3*(d*c+b)+a
```

**Given that all operations are binary, the general algorithm is:**

- If the element is an operand, then push (store) it into the stack.
- If the element is an operation, then pop (load) the two top most values from the stack, perform the operation on them, and push (store) the result back into the stack.